# Handle the row lock in multithreaded environment Using jdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, jdbctemplate

I'm working on Spring JPA and JdbcTemlapte mixed environment. Challenge is to update a row(Oracle) using jdbcTemplate in a multithreaded environment. So the question is how to lock the row and how to prevent deadlock scenarios?

Comment: well; which part is tasked to be multi-threaded here ? the programming layer(java+pl/sql) or the database layer(plain-sql) ? from what i have seen when people using java applets/jsp w/. Oracle 10g they write a select for update and then write the update immediately below

Comment: in programming layer

Comment: Which locking model are you planning to use (optimistic or pessimistic)? I couple of things I try to go by; 1. "Lock little, lock late, release early" and 2. try to update tables in the same order.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use `FOR UPDATE NOWAIT;` end of the select query. This avoids waiting for other transactions to release row locks.

Found a solution on [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/innodb-locking-reads.html).